# Prevent file to be readed from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I have a folder in my symfony project (3.3) called "**docs**".

I want to prevent the users to have access to it through the url (i.e : /docs/thedoc.pdf), but I need to keep the files inside it accessible for my program (because I read the file through a PHP file and display it in the browser).

I very new to all that .htaccess things, I found this complicated... any help would be appreciated =)

EDIT : I don't have access to the folder outside /www

Comment: You can move the files outside the web server's document root dir, and still access them from PHP.

Comment: I don't have access to folder outside of the /www, forgot to mention that sorry

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

> **Require all denied**
>   Access is denied unconditionally.

This means, if you put an `.htaccess` file in directory `docs` containing

```
Require all denied
```

then any request will be answered with an HTTP status code [403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors)

Comment: Will I be able to get my files through my program ?

Comment: @morganXap Yes, this directive restricts only requests made by HTTP clients. Unless your PHP script accesses the files via HTTP, there is no problem.